# Calling values from local JSON file using JQuery Typeahead Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js

I'm trying to call a nested value in a local JSON file using the JQuery Typeahead Plugin.

I have the following which uses the typeahead plugin:

```
$('#country_v1-query').typeahead({
    order: "desc",
    emptyTemplate: 'No result for "{{query}}"',
    source: {
        data: {
            url: ["/json/test.json", "data.country"]
        },
    },
    callback: {
        onInit: function (node) {
            console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
        },
        onSearch: function (node, query) {
            //console.log(query);
        }
    }
});
```

And the JSON file is:

```
{
        data: 
        {
            "country": 
            [
                "AfghanisTan",
                "Albania",
                "Algeria",
                "Andorra",
                "Angola",
                "Antigua and Barbuda",
                "Argentina",
                "Armenia",
                "Australia",
                "Austria",
                "Azerbaijan"
            ]
        }
}
```

I'm wanting to retrieve the 'country' value from the array. Could someone with better expertise in Jquery highlight the best way to do this?

Regards,
J

Comment: I can't figure out any other way of doing this. Apparently the "data.country" is supposed to bring back the suggested value?

Comment: You just had to fix the way you wrote your json, as well as taking "url" out of the data object. I wrote a detailed answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I took the "url" parameter out of the data: {} object and removed the data object:

```
source: {
    url: ["/json/test.json", "data.country"]
},
```

Also you must add double quotes around your 'data' object in json:

```
"data": { ... }
```

I put it all together for you below in case you still have trouble.

Full jquery code:

```
$('#country_v1-query').typeahead({
    order: "desc",
    emptyTemplate: 'No result for "{{query}}"',
    source: {
        url: ["/json/test.json", "data.country"]
    },
    callback: {
        onInit: function (node) {
            console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
        },
        onSearch: function (node, query) {
            //console.log(query);
        }
    }
});
```

Full JSON code:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "country": 
        [
            "AfghanisTan",
            "Albania",
            "Algeria",
            "Andorra",
            "Angola",
            "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina",
            "Armenia",
            "Australia",
            "Austria",
            "Azerbaijan"
        ]
    }
}
```